# Use of domain name

Tags: wp-admin, title, domain, migration

You may have to excuse my ignorance and lack of knowledge, I am totally new to WP. I need a new website, and I went to Register365 and bought my domain name. I had intended to use their "build your own website" service, and that they would host it. However, I find they could not fulfil my needs and I have decided to build a WP website. Can I still use the domain name which I have bought and paid for. It is a .ie domain name , and this is what I want to use ??
Thanks you,   Eamonn Nolan

Comment: Don't they have [1-click install for WordPress](https://www.register365.com/web-hosting/packages/compare)? To answer your question: Yes, you can use that domain for whatever you want - it belongs to you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your domain to build a website. In addition to the domain registrar, you will also need a web host. A recommendation would be far off-topic here but search for WordPress hosting, perhaps look through some reviews. I'd suggest chatting with their support team and if one stands out by answering your questions quickly and fully before you buy their hosting, that's a good one to try.